# highcharts: Other settings for y-axis. Dealing with large numbers

Tags: highcharts, logarithm

I am having some difficulty trying to manage/plot out large numbers in the y-axis in combination with small numbers.

Example's are here for both y-axis types: http://jsfiddle.net/index/6FBec/1/

For the first graph (linear): The problem's are that the small numbers gets plotted almost flat on the bottom.

For the second graph (logarithmic): Where as here (this is actually better), when the large number gets too large, the gap for the next tick is way far (graph2 last point 12,250 and largest y-axis is 100,000).

Question is, is there a different y-axis type or how can I do something like linear but when there is something too big it would do something like logarithmic like using smaller gaps on first then growing.

PS: Don't mind 0.1 value. Temp for logarithmic not wanting 0 values.

Answer (score 4):

I have Used some mathematic equations to reduce the gaps between points and still show the relative difference graphically.  To do this I process the data on the server and if a point is drastically different than another, then I will use a square root of both of them.  Here is a couple of examples that demonstrate this:

**VALUES: 220, 110, 55, 5**

- [**Normal Format**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbKtj/2/)
- [**Square Root Format**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbKtj/)

**VALUES: 1100, 220, 110, 55, 5**

- [**Normal Format**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbKtj/3/)
- [**Square Root Format**](http://jsfiddle.net/FbKtj/1/)

The data is sent as the square root rounded to the third decimal.  Then I use the formatter on the yAxis label and tooltip to display the proper values.  Also, I am making sure that the label displays as a whole number by using `parseInt`.

Comment: This is neat! I'll try it out and give feedback. Thanks! This looks highly effective to minimize gap.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest sticking to either linear or logarithmic, as these are kind of standards and would be intuitive for the user. These two suffice most of the visualization needs. The data that you are plotting in your example, is it production data? Is this how your data is going to be always, or just a one-off case? The easiest way to determine what axis to use is to find the variation or Standard Deviation or your data, if it is small use linear, if its large use logarithmic (the threshold of small & large can be tweaked based on your data).

I would say the visualizations that you have got in the jsFiddle are pretty much what you **should** use.

1) **Linear** You see one data point shooting out, and others are nearly (when compared to the largest in terms of %) same value. So you should very much show it as it, this gives the user a hint that something is terribly wrong. If you try to make the curve look *nice*, the user will always have to refer to the values and won't be able to make inferences just by looking at the graph, this is the whole purpose of charts. It won't make much sense to just a *good looking* graph when the user will have to go through the trouble of manually looking at the values of the data points to make quick inferences.

2) **Logarithmic** When your data is really skewed, yet there are pockets/clusters of data (not just one point being an outlier), go for this one.

If you must need to use some other scale (have a thorough understanding of your production data first, else you will end up *prettifying* your test data and mess up real data) use some similar standard like square or square root in @Dan Thomas's answer or best way is to if possible, get a generic (not real, but ideal way your data would be) equation for your data. So if your data is like `y=A*x`<sup>2</sup>`+ Bx + C`, go for squared, if it is of the form `y=A*x + B` go for linear, if `y=A*log+(x)+B` go for logarithmic and so on

More @ http://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/19/when-should-i-use-logarithmic-scales-in-my-charts-and-graphs/

Comment: I'm still contemplating on the other stuff, but to answer first the first question, this is a sample from our production data. We have different views and this only happens on some views (mostly when all data is viewed). So to answer, it won't always be like this.

Comment: ok, just keep the suggestion in mind, to not skew data for prettifying so much so that the visualization loses its visual clue, and the viewer needs to dig into values