# How to set minimum height of data element of series in stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to know how to set min height of data element of series. Eg:-If i have series [1000,400,200,500,10] and my Y-Axis max height is 1000..but when it will plot graph the height of last element of series "10" will be very small or negligible....i want to set condition that whatever the data of series the max height while ploting graph is 10 px. how to do it??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking for something like @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046508/highcharts-other-settings-for-y-axis-dealing-with-large-numbers/12048918#12048918

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `min` and `max` properties of the axis, like:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    }
```

Example taken from here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

API Documentation of the `min` option on an axis is availble here: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

API Documentation of the `max` option on an axis is availble here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max

Comment: thanks for reply but have look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/j8xZk/1/ where "Bananas" can't set minheight

Comment: Well, both `min` and `max` works as expected on the `y-axis` in the sample you refer to. It would be great if you could elaborate on the problem.